# java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol error

Tags: java, ant, semantic-web

I got this error on running ant for building the java code on Ubuntu. The application has to be deployed in the Tomcat web-app directory. When I run ant in my source directory, it builds all the files and deploys the application in the web-app directory. But, before completion it terminates with an error. The errors which I got are listed below.

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/manager/reload?path=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fokm%2Findex.jsp
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:585)    
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask.execute(ReloadTask.java:45)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use `file:///(the file)`.  The "protocol" the system wants here is `file:/`